# Create variable of proportions conditional on level of factor from subsets of data using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df<- data.frame(year= as.character(c("1997", 
"1997","1997","1997","1997","1997","1998","1998")),season= 
as.character(c("W", "W","W","D","D","D","W","W")),result= 
as.character(c("Y", "Y","N","N","Y","N","N","N")))
```

I would like to subset the data by `year` and `season` and calculate the proportion of "Y" in `result` for that particular subset. This new column of proportions is called `psit_freq`. An example of the output is below (I have made the proportions fractions to help readers understand the calculation I need).

```
output<- data.frame(year= as.character(c("1997", 
"1997","1998")),season= as.character(c("W", "D","W")), psit_freq= 
 as.character(c("2/3", "1/3","0/2")))
```

I have tried variations of:

```
df<- 
 df %>%
 group_by(year, season)%>%
 summarise(psit_freq= freq())
```

But am not sure how to incorporate the conditional if else statement to calculate the proportion of `Y` responses to the total  `result` rows in each subset.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer from below that you found most helpful (check mark to left of answers). This lets the community know the answer worked in your case.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware I did not accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.frame(year=as.character(c("1997","1997","1997","1997","1997","1997","1998","1998")),
           season=as.character(c("W", "W","W","D","D","D","W","W")),
           result=as.character(c("Y", "Y","N","N","Y","N","N","N"))) %>% 
  group_by(year, season) %>% 
  summarise(psit_freq = sum(result == "Y")/length(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is change `result` into an integer (or logical) and then group by `year` and `season` like you have and summarise taking the mean of `result`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  year= c("1997", "1997","1997","1997","1997","1997","1998","1998"),
  season= c("W", "W","W","D","D","D","W","W"),
  result= c("Y", "Y","N","N","Y","N","N","N")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(result = recode(result, "Y" = 1L, "N" = 0L)) %>% 
  group_by(year, season) %>% 
  summarise(psit_freq = mean(result))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   year [?]
#>    year season psit_freq
#>   <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1  1997      D 0.3333333
#> 2  1997      W 0.6666667
#> 3  1998      W 0.0000000
```